# Show that an element of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ commutes with everyone else.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $H:X\times I\to X$ a homotopy such that $H(x,0)=H(x,1)=x\ \forall x\in X$. We define the path $\gamma$ in $x_0$ as $\gamma(t)=H(x_0,t)$. Show that $[\gamma]$ commutes with every element of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$.

By definiton of the product in the fundamental group, if $[\beta]\in\pi_1(X,x_0)$ then $[\gamma][\beta]=[\gamma * \beta]$, where $*$ denotes the loop product. I've been trying to find a homotopy $G:I\times I\to X$  between $\gamma * \beta$ and $\beta * \gamma$ relative to $\{0,1\}$ without success. Could you please help me find it? Is there another method to show the result?

Answer (score 3):

You can use $H$ to "slide" $\beta$ along $\gamma$.
$$G(t) = \gamma|_{[0,t]}*(H_t\circ\beta)*\gamma|_{[t,1]}$$
will do, using the convention of following paths left-to-right with the path product $*$.  When $t=0$, it's $\beta*\gamma$, and when $t=1$ it's $\gamma*\beta$.  For intermediate $t$, you can check that the three paths are actually composable.

Comment: Homotopies usually have two parameters, I mean, I was searching for some $G(t,s)$. Does te other parameter remain unused?

Comment: $G(t)$ for a given $t$ is a path, so that is where the other parameter is used. I should have written $G_t$ perhaps.

Comment: I've got problems to show that $G$ preserves the base point for all $t$.
$G_t(0)=\gamma|_{[0,t]}(0)*(H_t(\beta(0)))*\gamma|_{[t,1]}(0)$. I would need $H_t(\beta(0))$ to be $\beta(0)$ for all $t$, but that's not necessary true.

Comment: Be careful with the definition of path composition, since it is actually shorthand for a piecewise function (and a reparameterization).  $G_t(0)=\gamma|_{[0,t]}(0)=x_0$.  By the way, you have to make a choice for what triple path composition means --- I was thinking $[0,1/3]$ for the first path, $[1/3,2/3]$ for the second, and $[2/3,1]$ for the third.